# Using WSDL service over https with certificate

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, certificate

I have same wsdl service, that I connected in VS,
certificate that I recieved from service administrator
and https adress for connection.
So, I need to call one method from this wsdl service (MigomCommonService) and this is my code for that:

```
            string adress = "https://xxxx.xxx.com/MigomCommonService/MigomCommonPort";
            string thumbprint = "xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx";

            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Name = "MigomCommonBinding";
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

            EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress(adress);

            MigomCommonService.MigomCommonPortTypeClient migomClient = new MigomCommonService.MigomCommonPortTypeClient(binding, addr);
            migomClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetCertificate(thumbprint);

            migomClient.Open();

            Session sessionPart = SessionPartRequest();
            string requestPart = CountryListRequest();
            string response = migomClient.MigomCommonOperation(ref sessionPart, requestPart);
```

When I'm calling MigomCommonOperation method I'm getting authentification error (407), but i can call this wsdl service via browser successfully.
What's wrong in this code? Maybe I forgot something in binding part or another thing ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this link will resolve your problem. access WCF endpoint through HTTPS protocol.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi
You need to install the certification to your local and trust it, then config the WCF servicepointmanager like :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
          new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler); 
        Service1Client obj = new Service1Client();
```